# C++ is executing cmd command by input possible?

Tags: c++, shell, cmd, system, execute

I want to create sth like:

```
int main ()
{
    string s{};
    
    std::cout << "Enter CMD: \n";
    
    getline(cin,s);
    
    system(s);
}
```

But since I can use only `const char` on `system`, its not working at all, is there any different solution to this? mabye shellexecute?

Comment: ***its not working at all*** The compiler should have given you an error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::string::c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/).

```
system(s.c_str());
```